# PHP add and update table with form

Tags: php, html

I have a webpage that gets input from the user with a form. after the user enters their input and picks a specific day in which the input should go under and clicks on the submit button I want to add their input into the table below. can someone show me how I can do this using PHP thank you. below is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Weekly Recipes </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="weeklyCalendarRepstyles.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="heading">
  <h2>Weekly Recipes</h2>
</div>

<form id="recipe-form">
  <input type="text" name="task" id="task" class="task_input">
  <select id="day">
    <option value="0">Sunday</option>
    <option value="1">Monday</option>
    <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="4">Thursday</option>
    <option value="5">Friday</option>
    <option value="6">Saturday</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" class="task_btn" name="submit">Add Recipe</button>

</form>

<div>
  <table id="t01">
    <tr>
      <th>Sunday</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</body>

<script> </script>
</html>
```

below is the css file for the webpage

```
 .heading {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6B8E23;
  background: #FFF8DC;
  border: 2px solid #6B8E23;
  border-radius: 20px
}

form {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FFF8DC;
  border: 1px solid #6B8E23;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

table#t01 th {
  background-color: #6B8E23;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Have you [**tried anything so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)?

Comment: Do you need it dynamically or statically

Comment: statically for now @vivekmodi

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use some php conditions and all like

```
    <tr>
    <td><?php if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']==0){echo $_POST['task'];;}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
    <td><?php if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']==1){echo $_POST['task'];;}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
    <td><?php if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']==2){echo $_POST['task'];;}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
    <td><?php if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']==3){echo $_POST['task'];;}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
    <td><?php if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']==4){echo $_POST['task'];;}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
    <td><?php if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']==5){echo $_POST['task'];;}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
    <td><?php if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']==6){echo $_POST['task'];;}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
  </tr>
```

Make your form method post and if you are using get then use $_GET instead of $_POST

Comment: hey, I tried this but it is not adding it to the table. the table just has '-' it will not update can you help

Comment: Have you submitted the form

Comment: yeah when i hit the Add Recipe button nothing changes

Comment: hey it works but every time i click add recipe the previous one disappears is there anyway to stop that

Comment: If you will use dynamic than it will be easy to keep this information

Comment: It's a big process you need to make database and table first then you can do this but wait for few minutes i will give you this solution without database it will stay till you didn't refresh the page @smith will it be ok you need database work only?

Comment: hey you still here